# Weird response from Exact Online API using Auth 2.0

Tags: php, api, exact-online

I was able to download some PHP code from exact online to connect to their API. Using this, I get logged in and get all the data such as my access token.

Now, when I do a simple http get on [start.exactonline.nl/api](https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/current/Me?$select=CurrentDivision) *(exactly as stated on their website)*, I get a 755 character string back with no meaning to me at all. Below a part of this string, just as an example, the original string I get back is way longer.

> ¶¨ÿ}6^¾œïvt6ù’Ì>L!3EOï>%àJ¿÷J'ó ü¸ßßAèðh”H ¥ÓÏx™1ëˆÒÝnçïú~©Vtþ•îèÍ”è ãsÃ½ëvkäÎa_äRÿÃ‡Ã#ãTaàôþÞˆíØKiP2?¬Ñƒ´^=ƒ{CBiÆ”F3º$WWƒ! =ê¨Œ09^*!x’lc²R‰?È#¸ISÔ„ŽR ¾A0%Q/­Q¢­\äÀ¢^.ËxÁÒ*+Un$:ÓjÄÏíÖR`ÎmØãšq.ä* ¬÷îagñ3´[Yx|ÕïùÖÀ‹±´ÌKuf³™

I should actually get an Json package back I suppose, or an error message, but I get this back.

Has anybody have a clue as to what is going on here or what I could check?

Comment: Can you show the code? Maybe the problem is your character set. They use UTF-8 so make sure you handle that request properly.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you add `CURLOPT_ENCODING => ''` to your cURL call, what you're receiving is a raw gzipped file.